# If $F\in \sigma(A)$ Then There Is $B \subset A$ Such That $F\in \sigma(B)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be set and let $A\subseteq P(X)$.

Show that if $F\in \sigma(A)$ then there is a countable set $B \subseteq A$ Such That $F\in \sigma(B)$

1. if $F$ is a family of sets, or at least one set, which is not a sigma-algebra, we can take $F=B$ and then $F\in \sigma(B)$ but I can not say that $B$ is countable set
2. if $F$ is a sigma-algebra , if $F=\sigma(A)$ there is $A\subseteq A$ such that $F\in \sigma(A)$, else we take $B$ to be all the elements $B=F\cap A$ and therefore $F\in \sigma(B)$ but again I can not say that $B$ is countable set

Comment: Using similar symbols for sets  and classes of sets makes things very confusing. That my be your main source of difficulty in answering this question. You could at least use bold letters for classes of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\{G: G \in \sigma (B) \, \text {for some countable set} \, B \subset A\}$. Verify that this is a sigma algebra and that it contains $A$. Conclude that it must contain $F$.